# Xcode cannot find label 'error' for PortAudio

Tags: c++, xcode, portaudio

I'm attempting to initialise portaudio as described in the [Initialising PortAudio tutorial](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/initializing_portaudio.html).

It says to check if there was an error during initialisation like so:

```
PaError err = Pa_Initialize();
if (err != paNoError) goto error;
```

Which is the exact code I'm using.

I'm running this on OS X Mojave 10.14.4, using Xcode 10.1 with the 10.12 OS X SDK.

I've attempted to find where the error label in the PortAudio docs to no avail, and there are no variables in the file named `error`.

The full program so far is:

```
# include <iostream>
# include "portaudio.h"
using namespace std;

// Typedef and demo callbacks here.

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    PaError err = Pa_Initialize();

    if (err != paNoError) goto error;

    // Nothing here yet.

    err = Pa_Terminate();

    if (err != paNoError)
    {
        printf("Port audio error terminating: %s", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell in the tutorial, this should be a valid statement, but Xcode shows the syntax error:
`Use of undeclared label 'error'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting the [c++ reference for goto statements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto) [an example program for PortAudio](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__sine_8c_source.html), the problem came from assuming that `goto` can access things defined in the portaudio.h file, which is not the case.

If you're having this issue, I assume you're also unfamiliar with `goto` statements.

The tutorial assumes there's a section of the main function dedicated to resolving errors. In order to resolve this issue, we need to define an error label in our `main` function that takes care of responding to errors.

For example:

```
int main(void) {
    PaError err;

    // Checking for errors like in the question code, including goto statement.

    return 1; // If everything above this goes well, we return success.

error:               // Tells the program where to go in the goto statement.
    Pa_Terminate();  // Stop port audio. Important!
    fprintf( stderr, "We got an error: %s/n", Pa_GetErrorMessage(err));
    return err;    
}
```